# Create a SOAP Webservice Client Application in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, client, cxf

I have created in eclipse a Webservice in Java using **Apache CXF**, now I have to create a WebService client application to consume and invoke it.
I have been searching a way to do it, and I found that Client is always dependent to the server's Java Class.

The problem is that I have to develop a client class in an other Java environment. My question is : Is there a way to develop a client class which will be independent of webservice server's package, using only the **WSDL** file ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve, but there are utilities that can be used to generate web service clients from a wsdl. wsimport comes as part of the standard jdk ( from Java 6 if I remember correctly )

Comment: You can generate classes by wsdl using cxf `wsdl2java` command or using jax-ws `wsimport`

Comment: I wish you had asked about NetBeans (Right click the project, new, Web Service Client, from WSDL, done)

Anyway - wsimport is sufficient for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of `Apache CXF` [Link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) wsdl to java tool. `wsdl2java` - takes a WSDL document and generates fully annotated Java code from which to implement a service.

You can take help of eclipse plugin also.

[Eclipse plugin to generate java class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/)

Answer (score 0):

You can send request to web service API as XML request. Only thing you would need to constuct SOAP complaint request with proper header and body. By using SoapUI you can generate the XML request structure, and then reuse it in your application.

If you are using Jax-RS(REST APIs), even http method also works

**[update]**

If you are stuck with  how to create client classes, then you would follow this

1. Use wsimport

   ```
   >  http : //hostname :port/wsdl.url on command line to create proxy classes
   ```
2. Create jar file generated proxy classes
3. Add jar file to class path
4. Use Service API to construct the end point, and then invoke service.
5. Sample test client is given below.

   ```
   try {

       URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost:8082/cxf/services/yourservice?wsdl");

       QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://package.name/","PORTNAme");

       Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);

       client = service.getPort(PORTInterface.class);

       client.executeYourMethod()

   } catch (Exception e) {

       // TODO Auto-generated catch block

       e.printStackTrace();

   }
   ```

> 

1. URL is WSDL url
2. To create QName, need to provide namespace of the service interface(revers name of package,usually) and PORT name which you can find in WSDL in binding section.
3. Also need to identify the Proxy class ( name would be similar to port name)

Cheers
Satheesh

Comment: Thank you :) Why create a proxy class ? I have used wsimport : `wsimport -keep -verbose http://127.0.0.1:8080/MCINTWebservice/services/McintWebservicePort?wsdl` and it generated me some classes..

Comment: What you generate from wsimport is nothing but proxy classe and dependencies to access your service. you would need to create instances of proxy(of your service) to call your service method/

Comment: Thank you I understand. I've created the jar, but Please I don't understand `Use Service API to construct the end point, and then invoke service.`

Comment: Once you created client jar add it to build path of your client project. Then you in-order to invoke the service method, you need to create instance of proxy. You can reuse the example I have provided. Updated my answer above

Comment: Thank you. my package is : `com.mcint.ws`, so it would be `http://ws.mcint.com`, and for the class Service do I have to use the proxy one or the Native class Java ? `PortInterface` would be the interface in Proxy classes right ? Finally PORTName, is it a field or an attribute ? what is it ? (Sorry I'm new on SOAP weservice) Thank you :)

Comment: PORTName not a field attribute, open your wsdl and you can find from binding section.